# Bitcoin Core QT Fatal Error after moving block folder, can't retrieve Private Key

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, synchronization, wallet-recovery

I have tried installing Bitcoin Core on my PC and without thinking, I went on and bought some coins (I was trying to be organized, so by the time the sync was done I would already have the coin).

90% into sync my HDD got full so I decided to go through this forum and see how to move the BLOCKS Folder to my `D:\ Drive`. After doing it the FATAL Error came and I am now unable to re-install the program EVEN After moving the BLOCK Folder back to the original folder.

Now I can't access my private key because I can't launch the program BUT I still have access to my `wallet.dat` (88KB).
I have search the forum for answers but can't find mine in particular.

Please help me retrieve my key!!

Comment: Just to understand what happened, did you move the folder while Bitcoin Core was running? As long as you have access to your `wallet.dat`, it should be possible to retrieve your keys. It would probably be helpful if you provided the error message.